# Do I need to create push notification service ssl certificates each when trying to create multiple apps with fcm functionality in apple developer?

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, apple-developer

(First of all, I understood that one key (Authkey) can be used for multiple apps.)

I am using p8 (authentication key method) rather than p12 (certificate method) for fcm setting.

I am
On the Apple developer site, click the app in the Identifiers tab and click edit in push notification.

[image]

After creating and downloading the Development SSL Certificate and the Production SSL Certificate, I can see that two certificates have been created in the Certificates tab of Apple developer: the push service and the Sandbox push service.

However, assuming that i want to create apps A and B use fcm, if each of the identifiers has to go through the above process, a total of 4 certificates, push services (2) and sandbox push services (2) will be generated. I am wondering if I can do it with .

In other words, I wonder if I need to create multiple push services in Certificates depending on the app?

[image]